# How to ignore words in string (FLEXIBLE) MATLAB

Tags: regex, string, matlab, performance

PARAMETERS(  1-  5)         a               b               c                 d                 e
PARAMETERS( 96-100)   ex1        ex2         ex(3)       ex4           ex5
PARAMETERS(101-105) ex1        ex2         ex3            ex(4)       ex5

I have each row inside a cell array, so when I read it I want to be able to ignore the parameters and whatever it's inside the parenthesis... I was using REGEX but it also ignores the parenthesis in the actual parameters like ex(4) and I have been trying all different ways I know and it's driving me crazy.

I want to be able to just ignore the word **'PARAMETERS(whatever is inside)'** without giving an specific number of characters to ignore so the file does not crash if they change anything apart from the word PARAMETERS and the parenthesis besides it.

Please Help!

Comment: Have you tried `PARAMETERS\(\s*?\d+\s*?-\s*?\d+\s*?\)(.+)` and accessing the first and only captured group?

Comment: So do you actually just want to capture everything after the first  closing parenthesis `')'`? Or do you think that there could be parentheses in the `'PARAMETERS(whatever is inside)'` part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the end result is to extract the 5 strings on the end of each line, in which case you can do this with two calls to [REGEXP](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html):

```
>> C = {'PARAMETERS( 1- 5)       a      b      c        d        e';...
        'PARAMETERS( 96-100)  ex1  ex2   ex(3)  ex4    ex5';...
        'PARAMETERS(101-105) ex1  ex2  ex3     ex(4)  ex5'};
>> sub = regexp(C, 'PARAMETERS\([^\)]+\)(.+)', 'tokens', 'once');
>> tokens = regexp(vertcat(sub{:}), '(\S+)', 'tokens');
>> tokens = cellfun(@(c) c{1}, vertcat(tokens{:}), 'UniformOutput', false)

tokens = 

    'a'      'b'      'c'        'd'        'e'  
    'ex1'    'ex2'    'ex(3)'    'ex4'      'ex5'
    'ex1'    'ex2'    'ex3'      'ex(4)'    'ex5'
```

As you can see, there's a lot of messiness involved in removing enclosing layers of cell arrays.

Comment: Thank you so much, I believe this is what tokens are for, I don't know if this is more efficient (time wise) than the third answer below but I will definetly compare! Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
PARAMETERS\(\s*\d+-\s*\d+\)(.+)
```

#### Demo

http://regex101.com/r/zG8xL6

Comment: Thanks for the info! this regex will be very useful for the rest of my code!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do this remove every thing before the first closing parenthesis without using regex, which can be very slow in Matlab – using [`strfind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html):

```
str = {'PARAMETERS( 1- 5)       a      b      c        d        e',
       'PARAMETERS( 96-100)  ex1  ex2   ex(3)  ex4    ex5',
       'PARAMETERS(101-105) ex1  ex2  ex3     ex(4)  ex5'};

str2 = cellfun(@(c1,c2)c1(c2(1)+2:end),str,strfind(str,')'),'UniformOutput',false)
```

If the data was originally in a file, it would probably be best to use [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) if possible for this. But once it's a bunch of lines in a cell array, `textscan` might not work as well. But you might still try it to see how well/fast it works in your case:

```
str2 = cellfun(@(c)textscan(c,'%s','CommentStyle',{'P',')'}),str);
[str2{:}]'
```

which returns:

```
ans = 

    'a'      'b'      'c'        'd'        'e'  
    'ex1'    'ex2'    'ex(3)'    'ex4'      'ex5'
    'ex1'    'ex2'    'ex3'      'ex(4)'    'ex5'
```

Or if you don't want the second part of the strings split up:

```
str2 = cellfun(@(c)textscan(c,'%s','CommentStyle',{'P',')'},'Delimiter',''),str);
[str2{:}]'
```

which returns a result identical the `strfind` solution:

```
ans = 

    'a      b      c        d        e'
    'ex1  ex2   ex(3)  ex4    ex5'
    'ex1  ex2  ex3     ex(4)  ex5'
```

Comment: Thank you so much I loved this answer